# Implementing a Preview channel of a vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to offer a preview version of my vscode extension so that user can get changes more frequently.

Essentially, I'd like to replicate what VSCode does:
* Stable: tested changes, happens every month/ad hoc
* Insiders: Daily build that gets sent to users

I noticed that the Visual Studio marketplace has a mechanism for marking an extension as "Preview" but this seems to be only cosmetic, in other words, it still overwrites the latest stable version of the extension.

I thought about publishing a new extension and calling that the "Preview" version, but then I want to only allow one of the extensions to be enabled at any given time because it's unclear how my extension will operate if you essentially have 2 extensions installed and running at the same time.

Has anyone tried this before? What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70249330/836330 this was added for v1.63.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no way to do this currently. The feature request is tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/15756)

Existing extensions—such as tslint—publish two versions: a normal release and a preview version

Comment: Thanks Matt. I looked up what tslint does and that seems like a reasonable approach at this time. For others, here is the tslint preview package:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.ts-tslint