# Is there a standard way to release preview features in VS Code extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My team is developing a [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) extension, and we're considering to release some of our new features as preview/beta only shown to a limited number of users.

We can think of ways to do it manually, but were wondering if Visual Studio Code provides any "standard" way to release such preview features, in a similar way as what is done for Visual Studio Code Insiders.

Is there a standard way to release preview features in VS Code extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think there's a standard way of doing this, which leads to different extensions taking different approaches:

- The [C# extension](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Installing-Beta-Releases) requires you to uninstall the marketplace / release version. Then you need to manually download the `.vsix` file for the beta release from GitHub and install the extension from that. It looks like the [Go extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/wiki/Use-the-beta-version-of-the-latest-Go-extension) is taking the same approach.
- Other extensions have two different versions published in the marketplace, such as [PowerShell](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell) and [PowerShell Preview](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell-Preview). The latter has a `preview` badge in the marketplace by specifying `"preview": true` in `package.json`:

  [image]

  This approach also requires manually uninstalling or disabling the original extension before you can use the preview version.
- Finally, some extensions include experimental features in regular marketplace releases, but lock them behind a setting so users can opt-in. There's some risk of breaking non-experimental functionality this way if things aren't tested well.

There's also an open feature request with a pretty lengthy discussion on this topic, so there might be an official solution someday:

- [Allow extensions to publish beta releases and users to opt-in to them (#15756)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15756)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! We'll likely go with the first option you mention.
Thanks also for linking this GitHub issue that I couldn't find, it sounds like something that could arrive soon!

Answer (score 2):

In vscode 1.63 an enhanced ability to preview `pre-release` extensions has been added, see [release notes: pre-release extensions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_63.md#pre-release-extensions).

> As VS Code now allows extensions to offer pre-releases, you can opt-in
> to install them and use the latest cutting edge features from
> extensions. VS Code shows an additional Install Pre-Release Version
> option in the extension Install drop-down menu for installing the
> pre-release version of the extension.

[image: pre-release extension menu]

> Once installed, the following indicators make it clear if you are
> using the pre-release version of an extension:

[image: pre-release extension identification]

> If there is a pre-release version of an extension that you have
> already installed you can easily switch to it:

[image: switch to a pre-release version]

---

To publish a pre-release version, see [release notes: publish pre-release extension versions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_63.md#publishing-pre-release-extensions).

> ##### Publishing Pre-Release Extensions
>
> VS Code now supports extension authors to publish pre-releases for
> their extensions through vsce by passing --pre-release flag. You can
> now make your latest features available to users who chose to install
> pre-releases and get early feedback before the official extension
> release.

`vsce publish --pre-release`

> VS Code Marketplace only support `major.minor.patch` for extension
> versions and semver pre-release tags are not supported. Support for
> this will arrive in the future. Because of this we recommend that
> extensions use `major.EVEN_NUMBER.patch` for release versions and
> `major.ODD_NUMBER.patch` for pre-release versions. For example:
> `0.2.*` for release and `0.3.*` for pre-release. VS Code will auto
> update extensions to the highest version available, so even if a user
> opted into a pre-release version and there is an extension release
> with a higher version, that user will be updated to the released
> version.

More information about pre-release extensions can be found in the [Pre-Release Extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/working-with-extensions/publishing-extension#pre-release-extensions) topic.

Comment: Of interest for VSCode 1.66: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/143540